# Symfony Voter : Access denied, the user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me

Tags: php, symfony, security

I'm pretty new to Symfony. I'm trying tu use a Voter on an Admin area.

I want an admin (ROLE_ADMIN) to be able to delete (remove) a user only if he's a superAdmin (ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN).

My Firewall seems to work fine as i can login on the admin area and do what i want till i'm not using the Voter. Here's a dump of my curent User Object :

```
User {#300 ▼
  -id: 1
  -password: "$2y$13$e3LL2N/pYGrGn.7EFikqSuAMSkLolcnggtf1HsBgNMzdXnal1AIua"
  -username: "JustMe"
  -email: "me@me.fr"
  -isActive: true
  -roles: array:1 [▼
    0 => "ROLE_ADMIN"
  ]
}
```

As soon as i use denyUnlessGranted() in my controller i get this Exception :

```
DEBUG - Access denied, the user is neither anonymous, nor remember-me.
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: "Access Denied." at /Volumes/Work/MAMP htdocs/a-symfony-re/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php line 119
```

This is my security config :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_AUTHOR: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_EDITOR: ROLE_AUTHOR
    ROLE_ADMIN : [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/
        provider: app_users_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: jst_login
            check_path: jst_login_check
        logout:
            path: jst_logout
            target: /

access_decision_manager:
    strategy: unanimous
```

This is a basic action in my controller that works fine till a'm not using the voter :

```
public function deleteUserAction(User $user)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('delete', $user);
    $currentUser = $this->getUser();
    $role = $currentUser->getRoles[0];

    return new Response('Delete User AppBundle:AdminController:deleteUser : '.$role);
}
```

And this is very simple Voter :

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface;

class UserVoter extends Voter
{
    const EDIT = 'edit';
    const DELETE = 'delete';
    const CREATE = 'create';

    private $decisionManager;

    public function __construct(AccessDecisionManagerInterface, $decisionManager)
    {
        $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
    }

    public function support($attribute, $subject)
    {
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(selt::DELETE))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$subject instanceOf USER) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $currentUser = $token->getUser();
        $user = $subject;

        if (!$currentUser instanceOf User) {
            return false;
        }

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::DELETE :
                //return $this->canDelete( $token );
                return $this->canDelete($user, $currentUser);
                break;
            default:
                throw new \LogicException('this code shoudn\'t be executed');
        }
    }

    private function canDelete($user, $currentUser)
    {
        //return $this->decisionManager->decide( $token, array( 'ROLE_ADMIN' ) );
        return $currentUser->getRoles()[0] == 'SUPER_ADMIN';
    }
}
```

As you can see i've already tryied to use AccessDecisionManagerInterface with no result ..

Et bien heuuu .. any help ? ;-)

Thanck's !

Comment: You've got a typo in your `support` fonction: `selt::DELETE` should be `self::DELETE` ?

Comment: You right ! but still got this exception ..

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` in your role_hierarchy ?

try this in your `voteOnAttribute` function.

```
  case self::DELETE:
            // if the user is an super admin, allow them to create new posts
            if ($this->decisionManager->decide($token,  array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'))) {
                return true;
            }
```

When you are logged to the website, what is your role ? Check the profiler

Comment: I had omited the role yeah, but still got that problem. Also tried to simply trying to match against ROLE_AMDIN but still throw the Exception. I'm loggin in under ADMIN_ROLE

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a role `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` in your security config.
Add it in your role hierarchy:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_AUTHOR: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_EDITOR: ROLE_AUTHOR
    ROLE_ADMIN : [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
...
```

**Update after comment**

The problem for `//return $this->decisionManager->decide( $token, array( 'ROLE_ADMIN' ) );` is, where is your logic defining if a user can delete another one?
The decisionManager doesn't know if you don't implement the interface and use that instance.

For `return $currentUser->getRoles()[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN';` well, maybe the user returned by the token storage has several roles, and `ROLE_ADMIN` is not the first one. In this case try use:

```
return in_array("ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN", $tokenInterface->getUser()->getRoles();
```

Comment: Yes i had forgotten the ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN role un security.yml  but still throws the same error. ANy way i've also tried to simplify the Voter trying to match against a ROLE_ADMIN but still throws the Exception. I've tried 2 methods in my Voter : return $this->decisionManager->decide( $token, array( 'ROLE_ADMIN' ) ); and return $currentUser->getRoles()[0] == 'ROLE_ADMIN'; both methods are failing.

Comment: Ok i finally found few errors in my code. Thank's a lot for the advices. But 1 point seems to be noticed : In a Voter Custom Class,  WE CAN USE AccessDecisionManager as it holds the logic by checking the Token User roles. So $this->decisionManager->decide( $token, array( "ROLE_ADMIN" ) ); works great. Here were my typos & errors : 1 : Coma after constructor argument type, 2 : unsupported method"support" ("supports" is the good one) and above all, i had miss configured my service in app/config/services.yml.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by an incompatibility between symfony 3.0 and the `jms/security-extra-bundle` in version 1.6.0.

If you use jms-security-extra-bundle try using it in version 1.6.1 or higher!